# emacs shell sync directory

Tags: emacs

I encounter this quite a lot. when I open a emacs shell and run **M-x dirs** it will complain to me that:**couldn't cd** or sometimes **just hang emacs** what is the solution for this ?

**What shell are you running?**
I am using: GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.22.1) of 2012-02-07; not the eshell, but the builtin emacs shell

**Have you customized shell-dirstack-query?**
tried, but I don't have this variable in my emacs

**Are you issuing M-x dirs at the shell prompt?**
yes

**Does the dirs command do what it normally does?**
yes, sometimes

**What does your prompt look like?**
if it finished successfully then it will echo dirs and the PWD

@Gilles

Comment: What shell are you running? Have you customized `shell-dirstack-query`? Are you issuing `M-x dirs` at the shell prompt? Does the `dirs` command do what it normally does? What does your prompt look like?